# Firebase Storage UI - takes too much time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am using Firebase Storage UI to get images from storage. I store file url in the database but get those images it takes too much time (maybe 5 mins on Wi-Fi). Some of images have high quality therefore their size is also around 11 MB.

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(item.getPhoto());
    dogBreedName.setText(item.getName());
    Glide.with(activity)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .into(dogBreedPhoto);
```

I could scale the image a little bit but I dont want to lose the quality. Do you know about another solution?

Comment: hi, did you get a solution to this issue? if so, please help here http://stackoverflow.com/q/42480626/3671509

Answer (score 0):

its a bit late but still if you didnt find an answer you can try this out

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(item.getPhoto());
    dogBreedName.setText(item.getName());
    Glide.with(activity)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(dogBreedPhoto);
```

adding dontAnimate() worked for me